# How to get bitmap from dwg trueview control

Tags: c#, dwg

we are developing an architectural software. C# WinForm application. We are using DWG TrueView control to display a DWG drawing on the form. We want to get image of this drawing and want to show on active report. Is there a way to get the image/bitmap of this dwg from the viewer.

Comment: Is there a `DrawToBitmap()` method like all of the built-in controls? If not, that's a good reason you should be using the built-in controls. I have no idea what DWG is.

Comment: Are you wanting a thumbnail or the full size drawing?

Comment: @ Mark thank you I am writing a full size image

Comment: Resolved this using BitBlt Thanks a lot